# change position panel

Tags: asp.net, html, css, stylesheet

```
<table> 
  <tr><td>  
     <asp:Panel ID="PanelButtomEnter" runat="server" >
      </asp:Panel>
  </tr></td>
</table>

 protected void brtnEnterProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    //how can change position panel
 }
```

how can change position panel on page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have `</tr></td>` but it should be `</td></tr>`.

Second, while applying `style.top` and `style.left`, you should also apply `style.position="absolute"`, like this:

```
this.PanelButtomEnter.Style.Add("position","absolute");
this.PanelButtomEnter.Style.Add("top","100px");
this.PanelButtomEnter.Style.Add("left","100px");
```

These 3 values should work.

I hope this helps.

See following MSDN articles.

[WebControl.Style Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.style.aspx)

[CssStyleCollection.Add Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83zf8zd5.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The better approach will be using Styles. Try this code.

```
this.PanelButtomEnter.Styles.Add("Top","100");
this.PanelButtomEnter.Styles.Add("Left","100");
```

Comment: then I don't think you can't do it.