# Position of a panel within another panel. ASP

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I'm trying to position a panel inside another panel with the following code.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim pbdoors As New Panel With
        {
            .Width = 110,
            .Height = 435,
            .BackImageUrl = "~/Images_temp/S1.bmp"
        }

        Dim pbdoors_B As New Panel With
        {
            .Width = 98,
            .Height = 98,
            .BackImageUrl = "~/Images_temp/V1.bmp"
        }

        Panel1.Controls.Add(pbdoors)
        pbdoors.Controls.Add(pbdoors_B)

End Sub
```

But for the Panel pbdoors_B object, I can't add the position as it was done in VB.NET.

```
pbdoors.Location = New Point(10, 10)
```

I understand that it is different in ASP (.Top, .Left), but please, can you tell me what the syntax would be to do it from the button in VB.NET? Is it possible?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite panel.location.X or Y can't be changed (I don't really understand why - compiler say "it's a value" and so what ?) you can set left and top position in this way :

```
pbdoors.Left = 30
pbdoors.Top = 30
```

EDIT: preceding is for winform.
for asp.net change style ([change position panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322290/change-position-panel)) :

```
pbdoors.Style.Add("position","absolute")
pbdoors.Style.Add("top","100px")
pbdoors.Style.Add("left","100px")
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I entered the sentence as you commented, but it shows an error message that `.Left` and `.Top` are not members of the Panel type object. I´m using ASP.NET and VB.NET, any idea?

Comment: I updated answer for asp.net